# How can I find out which capabilities a docker container requires to run

Tags: docker

Is there a way to determine the capabilities a docker container needs to run?
Is there some kind of logging of unavailable capabilities when a container fails to run due to restrictions that would be satisfied by a given capability?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43621959/how-can-i-find-out-which-capabilities-a-container-has-been-given